# Which Suitable Way For XML Conversion Dynamic using ASP.NET Console Application Without XSLT?

Tags: asp.net, xml, console-application, roku, brightscript

First, I create successfully web API in ASP.NET. API getting the XML from another server. I find the which suitable for XML all format change.

I tried to apply belove logic:

```
 using (XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create("XML.xml"))
 {
    //String starttime,Endtime;
    while (reader.Read())
    {
        // Only detect start elements.
        if (reader.IsStartElement())
        {
            switch (reader.Name)
            {                           
                   case "EventInfo":
                   // Detect this element.
                   Console.WriteLine("Start <content> element.  ");
                   Console.WriteLine();
                   break;
             }
         }
     }
}
```

in this way only single file convert into another file.
I tried to create multiple files at a time convert into another format.

I gave the below format data from web API
It's a Normal XML Format Use:

```
<EventInfo>
   <Event>
        <EventId>1</EventId>   
        <EventName>shedule-1</EventName>   
        <EventText>ch1 Channel Description</EventText> 
        <StartTime>00:00:00</StartTime>
        <Duration>00:30:00</Duration>
        <Date>20.06.2019</Date>
   </Event>
<EventInfo>
```

I apply the Logic in title tag its a starttime+duration is my end time and I Display EventName and Time both in tile tag.its all in dynamic.

Here Its ROKU format XML:

```
<Content>

      //Here i only print the HH-MM.
      <item title="00:00 - 00:30 shedule-1" LIVE="true" streamformat="mov" description="ch1 Channel Description" realeasedate="20.06.2019" description-color="0xC36419"/>

<Content>
```

Anyone know which is the best way to converting the XML. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Please check out the below solution for your case:

1) Deserialize WebAPI Xml to C# object (say Events).

2) From (Events) C# object to required xml format using xml Linq.

Click [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/rz4lDY) - For online execution

Step 1: Create a Class to deserailize the input xml structure.

```
public class Event
{
    [XmlElement]
    public string EventId { get; set; }
    [XmlElement]
    public string EventName { get; set; }
    [XmlElement]
    public string EventText { get; set; }
    [XmlElement]
    public string StartTime { get; set; }
    [XmlElement]
    public string Duration { get; set; }
    [XmlElement]
    public string Date { get; set; }
}
```

Step 2: Deserialize WebAPI Xml string to C# object and Reformat using xml linq.

```
string sXml = @"<EventInfo>
                           <Event>
                                <EventId>1</EventId>   
                                <EventName>shedule-1</EventName>   
                                <EventText>ch1 Channel Description</EventText> 
                                <StartTime>00:00:00</StartTime>
                                <Duration>00:30:00</Duration>
                                <Date>20.06.2019</Date>
                           </Event>
                        </EventInfo>";

        using (TextReader oReader = new StringReader(sXml))
        {
            // Deserialize Xml string to c# object
            XmlSerializer xmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<Event>), new XmlRootAttribute("EventInfo"));
            List<Event> lstEvents = (List<Event>)xmlSerializer.Deserialize(oReader);

            if (lstEvents != null)
            {
                // Restructure the C# object to ROKU Xml Format using Xml Linq
                XElement oResult = new XElement("Content", lstEvents.Select(t =>
                                new XElement("item",
                                    new XAttribute("title", string.Format("{0} - {1} {2}", Convert.ToDateTime(t.StartTime).ToString("HH:mm"), Convert.ToDateTime(t.Duration).ToString("HH:mm"), t.EventName)),
                                    new XAttribute("LIVE", "true"),
                                    new XAttribute("streamformat", "mov"),
                                    new XAttribute("description", t.EventName),
                                    new XAttribute("realeasedate", t.Date),
                                    new XAttribute("description-color", "0xC36419")
                                    )));
                // Saving the output as seperate xml file
                oResult.Save("ROKU.xml");                   
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("No Events Found");
            }

        }
}
```

Comment: @NikunjChaklasiya - There should be one xml response => corresponding one xml output is enough . That's my understanding - Am I correct ?

Comment: Thank you it's working But one issue is remaining converter is done But `<EventInfo>
   <Event>
        <EventId>1</EventId>   
        <EventName>shedule-1</EventName>   
        <EventText>ch1 Channel Description</EventText> 
        <StartTime>00:00:00</StartTime>
        <Duration>00:30:00</Duration>
        <Date>20.06.2019</Date>
   </Event>
<EventInfo>` this one is First part of xml

Comment: and   `<OtherMovies> <movieid>28</movieid><MovieName>Coyote Trails</MovieName><MovieLink>http://203.100.70.134:6585/Movie/10.mp4</MovieLink><Active>1</Active><Hrs>3</Hrs><Mins>0</Mins><YearOfRelease>2002</YearOfRelease><Genre>17</Genre><Description>Description here</Description><Price>0.99</Price><Days>30</Days><Poster>file-1560841310439.JPG</Poster><Thumbnail>file-1560841262846.JPG</Thumbnail><IsDeleted>0</IsDeleted><GenreId>17</GenreId><GenreName>Romance</GenreName>
</OtherMovies>` here the second part but I will get the same XML and convert it and store different XML which is possible.

Comment: @NikunjChaklasiya - Please post your full web API response - Expected xml structure in each case.

Comment: hello you invite me in your room

Comment: my web API response is so lengthy so I ask.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/195496/discussion-between-user2932057-and-nikunj-chaklasiya).